# how to translate Haskell into Scalaz?

Tags: scala, haskell, functor, scalaz

One of my high school students and I are going to try to do a port of Haskell's Parsec parser combinator library into Scala. (It has the advantage over Scala's built-in parsing library that you can pass state around fairly easily because all the parsers are monads.)

The first hitch I've come across is trying to figure out how Functor works in scalaz. Can someone explain how to convert this Haskell code:

```
data Reply s u a = Ok a !(State s u) ParseError
                 | Error ParseError


instance Functor (Reply s u) where
    fmap f (Ok x s e) = Ok (f x) s e
    fmap _ (Error e) = Error e -- XXX
```

into Scala (using Scalaz, I assume). I got as far as

```
sealed abstract class Reply[S, U, A]
case class Ok[S, U, A](a: A, state: State[S, U], error: ParseError)
    extends Reply[S, U, A]
case class Error[S, U, A](error: ParseError) extends Reply[S, U, A]
```

and know that I should make `Reply` extend the `scalaz.Functor` trait, but I can't figure out how to do that. (Mostly I'm having trouble figuring out what the `F[_]` parameter does.)

Any help appreciated!

Thanks,
Todd

Based on dflemstr's answer, I came up with this:

```
sealed abstract class Reply[S, U, A]
object Reply {
  implicit def ReplyFunctor[S, U]  = {
    type ReplySU[A] = Reply[S, U, A]
    new Functor[ReplySU] {
      def fmap[A, B](r: ReplySU[A], f: A => B) = r match {
        case Ok(a, state, error) => Ok(f(a), state, error)
        case Error(error) => Error[S, U, B](error)
      }
    }
  }
}
case class Ok[S, U, A](a: A, state: State[S, U], error: ParseError) 
    extends Reply[S, U, A]()
case class Error[S, U, A](error: ParseError) extends Reply[S, U, A]()
```

What I'm not sure about is that `ReplySU[A]` type. The actual `Functor` in Haskell is `Reply s u` with curried types and the `a` type missing. Is this how I should do the same thing in Scala or am I overly complicating things?

Comment: Scala parsers are monads too ! A Scala monad is any object with implementations for `map` and `flatMap` methods (provided they satisfy monad axioms).

Comment: It looks like you've already got your answer, but for future, feel free to drop in. irc://freenode.net/#scalaz

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `Functor[F[_]]`, the `F` means that it is a *type constructor*, that is, a parameterized type that must take some other type as a parameter to become a fully qualified type. For instance, if `F` is `List`, then `List[Int]` is a type instance of that parameterized type.

So when you define a value of type `Functor[List]`, it means that it is an object describing the functor nature of `List`s, and that the functor object will use the higher-order type `List` to construct various type instances, such as `List[A]` and `List[B]`.

Further, you must understand the difference between Scala's classes and Haskell's classes. A class instance in Haskell is best modeled by an implicit value in Scala, rather than the implementation of an interface; while you need an *instance of an object* to also have an *instance of an interface* in Java/Scala, you can have an *instance of a class* in Haskell without having an instance of the type of value that the class deals with.

Imagine, for example, how you would implement the [`Read`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t:Read) class from Haskell in Scala. The `Read` class deserializes values from strings; there is a function called `read` with type `Read a => String -> a` so for any type `a` which has a `Read` instance, you can convert a `String` into an instance of type `a`. If you model it using an interface in Scala, such that `class Foo implements Read[Foo]`, how would you then convert a string into an instance of `Foo`? You can't call `Foo.read` because you don't have a `Foo` yet; the `read` function is supposed to return one!

Instead, you create a separate `ReadFoo: Read[Foo]` object that contains the implementations of the functions of `Read` for the type `Foo`. Then you can call `ReadFoo.read(string: String): Foo` and get a `Foo` back type-safely.

For a functor instance, what you need is the following:

```scala
// All implicits in the companion object of Reply are automatically brought into
// scope when Reply is imported
object Reply {
  // Describes how to treat a `Reply` as a functor
  implicit val ReplyFunctor: Functor[Reply] = new Functor[Reply] {
    def fmap[A, B](r: Reply[A], f: A => B) = r match {
      case Ok(x, s, e) => Ok(f(x), s, e)
      case err         => err // leave value unchanged
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to fiddle with this a little bit today before I accept the answer (just in case I need to ask for clarification).

Comment: Can you take a look at my edit above to make sure I'm on the right track?

Comment: I think that you can replace the `ReplySU` type with `scalaz.PartialApply2Of3[Reply, S, U]#Apply`. Then you also don't have to create that inner block with the new specialized type. Also, I seem to have completely forgotten that `Reply` took more than one type parameter in my answer, apologies!

Comment: You can also see [how some of the standard functors are implemented](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Functor.scala); they use an anonymous type function for situations like this (See Tuple2 for example).

Comment: Thanks. `PartialApply` was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

Ah you mean a port like this:
https://github.com/runarorama/scarpia
?
In general this side is used not to much(sadly):
https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Tools+and+Libraries

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it looks like someone got started and never finished with Scarpia.

Comment: @TOB FWIW, Rúnar Bjarnason, aka apocalisp, is one of Scalaz main contributors, and, iirc, one of the authors of Scala's Packrat Parsers.